# Combinations of rows and columns / different states

Tags: combinatorics

We have a rectangular array 23x24 of leds and 47 switches, each of them swapping the state of one row or column.
Suppose we are allowed to turn the switch as many times we want and at any order, calculate all possible different arrangements of leds that we can have, if the initial state is with all leds being off (two arrangements are considered as different if at least one led is on in one arrangement and off in the other).

I think all possible states are 23x24 but some are double-counted?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it just be $2^{47}$?

Edit: Or maybe $2^{46}$

Comment: R. Emery: Yes maybe you are right: But I am thinking of the following: If for all 47 leds we could have one of the two states 1 or 0, it would be 2^47. But now, with every turn of a switch, we change the state of all leds in one row or column. Therefore we can't have only one led turned on (or off) in one row, unless we have turned this switch on, and (n-1) of the switches of the columns off.

Comment: Maybe reduce it to 2 rows and 2 columns

Comment: We need to examine whether it is possible to have ALL arrangements. For example, if we name C1, C2, ..., C23 the columns and R1,R2, ..., R24 the rows, can we ever get the arrangement where only R1C1 and R24C22 are on, and all others off? How did we arrive to this arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that having all arrangements is not possible. If we have a $23 x 24$ matrix, then that means we could have $2^{(23x24)}$ combinations, which is not right. Instead, you can decide a combination by first picking a switch arrangement for the rows and then for the columns. Since switching any switch more than once will only repeat combinations, this is sufficient. This gives you $2^{23}$ combinations for the rows and $2^{24}$ for the columns. Thus, you get $2^{24}*2^{23}$. However,there are some repetitions. Consider the case when all row switches are on or all column switches are off.

Comment: I am not sure that switching any switch more than once will only repeat combinations. Each switch reverses the current state in its row or column. If all row switches are on, given that we start with all lets at the "off" state, then all leds will be on. However, with some combinations of rows and columns switches, we can get selective leds on only.

Comment: What I mean is that if you switch a row switch twice, for example, you essentially reverse back to the original led state. You could switch a column in between, but that would still be equivalent to just having done the one column switch.